# What does this "ICAgICAg…" mean in public key certificates and messages?

Tags: encoding

I noticed that the string `ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg`, in various repeating lengths, appears fairly often in public key certificates and ciphertexts.

What does this mean? Is it some kind of padding? Is it a quirk of the encryption?

Comment: Are you sure about the ciphertexts? It's actually impossible as the result of any usable encryption is a random-looking byte sequence. The probability of 15 consecutive spaces is 2**-120, i.e., practically zero.

Comment: It means the certificate is made out of a polymer of Silver, Iodine and Carbon. The length of the chain depends on how long the certificate needs to be.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`ICAg` represents three spaces when text is base64-encoded.

For example:

```
echo -n '      hello world' | openssl base64
```

produces:

```
ICAgICAgaGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why three spaces might be a common occurrence in public key certificates?

Comment: Any long string of spaces would turn into n blocks of 3 spaces plus a maybe a final block of one or two spaces plus other characters

Comment: @DélissonJunio it should not be a common occurrence. There's no reason to add pointless blank space to a certificate, and in a ciphertext it's even more concerning.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica My guess is that the text before encoding had indentation using spaces.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica Certificates do not contain any ciphertext.  They often contain base-64 encoded text though.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica I know... "appears fairly often in public key certificates and ciphertexts"

Answer (score 31):

The accepted answer doesn't show how to get the answer (it shows, how to verify it). Use

```
echo 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg' | base64 -d
```

(producing a bunch of spaces) or

```
echo 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg' | base64 -d | hexdump -C
```

producing

```
00000000  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20     |               |
0000000f
```

to see what's inside.